# Be more efficient in VBA coding --> efficient VBA looping

Tags: excel, vba, performance

could you assist me in writing the code below more efficiently please? I am working on a Master List, where I am copying data from various sources for each month into the columns Z, AC, AF, AI etc. (always separated by 2 columns). Then I copy that cell all the way down to update the values for each row. As you can see in the code below, the only difference from one section of the code to the next is:

- Change column (here Z to AC)
- Change paths which are stored in different cells (e.g. fromPath changed to fromPath2.

How can I make it more efficient? Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Take care

```
' Update Jan 2018

fromPath = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017").Range("G2")
vbaPath = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017").Range("F2")
vbaFile = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017").Range("H2")
Orderlist2017 = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017").Range("I2")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orderlist P25 2017")
Range("Z10").Formula = "=VLookup(C10,  '" & vbaPath & vbaFile & Orderlist2017 & "'!C14:Z90, 8, False)"
Range("Z10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Y10").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("Z85").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With

' Update Feb 2018

fromPath2 = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017").Range("G3")
vbaPath2 = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017").Range("F3")
vbaFile2 = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017").Range("H3")
Orderlist2017 = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017").Range("I3")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orderlist P25 2017")
Range("AC10").Formula = "=VLookup(C10,  '" & vbaPath2 & vbaFile2 & Orderlist2017 & "'!C14:Z90, 8, False)"
Range("AC10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Y10").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("AC85").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With
```

Comment: If the code works, then it is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow and would be more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the code does not really work as it takes ages to load and causes my computer often to crash. Hence I would be keen to write it differently. Hope its clear. Thanks

Comment: To clarify, by "crash" to you mean "Excel goes (not responding)"? because that's not what *crashing* is and if that's the case, @cybernetic.nomad is correct.

Comment: `With` doesn't work the way that you seem to think that it works. In the body of `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orderlist P25 2017")`, it isn't true that `Range()` automatically refers to that sheet. On the other hand `.Range()` (note the dot) would.

Comment: Start by using a variable and not typing `Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017")` over and over.  And qualify that sheet with a workbook - alsways be specific when referring to ranges or it will come back to bite you...

Comment: Hi, I did that and I changed all the .Select with .Filldown. But the same problem remains: I always need to manually change the paths (vbapath, vbapath2, vbapath3, vbapath4 etc..) I have more than 200 paths. Isnt there a way to assign variables so Excel can do the loop automatically? Hope its clear

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most effective way to speed up most macros is to turn off screen updating.  Also, turning off automatic calculation can help a lot, if your worksheet contains a lot of formulas.  I created a method to do this, called "FastMode" which I use in every VBA project I create.  At the top of your macro, call it with the parameter set to "True" to make your code run fast, then at the end, call it with "False" to restore the default Excel settings.

```
Public Sub FastMode(ByVal blnMode As Boolean)

  'set workbook to fast mode (or back to normal mode) to speed up any process
  'that modifies the worksheets

   On Error Resume Next

   With Application

      Select Case blnMode
         Case True
           .ScreenUpdating = False
           .Calculation = xlCalculationManual

         Case False
           .ScreenUpdating = True
           .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

      End Select

   End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  Untested, but should get you started.

```
Sub TT()

    Dim fromPath, vbaPath, vbaFile, Orderlist2017
    Dim shtPaths As Worksheet, shtOrders As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, rngFormula

    Set shtPaths = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017") 'ThisWorkbook?
    Set shtOrders = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orderlist P25 2017")

    Set rngFormula = shtOrders.Range("Z10") '<< first vlookup goes here

    For i = 1 To 12 'for example...

        fromPath = shtPaths.Range("G2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        vbaPath = shtPaths.Range("F2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        vbaFile = shtPaths.Range("H2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        Orderlist2017 = shtPaths.Range("I2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value

        'you can assign the formula directly to the required range
        ' (exactly what you want here is not clear from your posted code...)
        rngFormula.Resize(76, 1).Formula = "=VLookup(C10,  '" & vbaPath & vbaFile & Orderlist2017 & "'!C$14:Z$90, 8, False)"

        Set rngFormula = rngFormula.Offset(0, 2) 'move over two columns

    Next i

End Sub
```